# How to store values in embedded function

Tags: r

Yet another beginner question. Here is example:

```
store <- as.numeric()
multi.fun <- function(x) { t <- x*2; return(t) }
main.fun <- function(x) { store[i] <- multi.fun(x)+x; sum(tail(store,2)) }

x <- 1:10

ret <- as.numeric()

for(i in 1:10) {
 print(main.fun(x[i])); Sys.sleep(0.2)
}
```

Is it possible to assign values at each iteration to the `store` object?

EDIT: That means it would be evaluated inside the function so that the last sum(tail(..,2)) would give final result:

```
9 15 21 27 33 39 45 51 57
```

and the `store[i] <- multi.fun(x)+x` would give:

```
[1] 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
```

Comment: hm, I know about that, but I would need to get the `store` values earlier. Evaluated kind of inside the function already. It seems that what I'm asking is not correct.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest you should delete your question. In fact, I just finished writing an answer as I got the popup saying it was deleted. Fwiw, it's posted in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you probably need is the `<<-` operator which allows you to access objects in the Global environment (on this occasion).

Writing the main function as:

```
main.fun <- function(x) { store[i] <<- multi.fun(x)+x; sum(tail(store,2)) }
```

Your process does what you want it to do:

```
store <- as.numeric()
multi.fun <- function(x) { t <- x*2; return(t) }
main.fun <- function(x) { store[i] <<- multi.fun(x)+x; sum(tail(store,2)) }

x <- 1:10

ret <- as.numeric()

for(i in 1:10) {
  print(main.fun(x[i])); Sys.sleep(0.2)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 3
[1] 9
[1] 15
[1] 21
[1] 27
[1] 33
[1] 39
[1] 45
[1] 51
[1] 57
```

However, it is usually not a good idea to use a function to change objects in the Global environment because it is prone to creating errors.

Comment: that's exactly it. I never used that `<<-` before. Thanks! How is that operator called?

Comment: Just be careful @Maximilian, these `<<-`'s can come back to bite you and if others ever need to use or modify your code it could be highly problematic.  You should really try to use vectorized operations and demark your steps vs generate functional side effects with two unnaturally scoped variables (`i` and `store`).